# how to retrieve complete version history for multiplecolumns using spservices in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

how to retrieve complete version history for multiple columns using spservices in SharePoint online by using this iam able to retrive single column data , how to get multiple columns data

```
 $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetVersionCollection",
                    async: false,
                    strlistID: "list1",                    
                    strFieldName: "column1",                    
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        console.log(xData);
                        $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function (i) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSOM/REST APIs do currently not support retrieving the list item versions and their metadata. But it looks like it's coming (soon). See UserVoice suggestion [Provide items version history with CSOM](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147150-provide-items-version-history-with-csom)

Until then you can use the [GetVersionCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getversioncollection(v=office.12).aspx) method of the Lists.asmx service. The downside here is that it's a SOAP service and you can only retrieve the history of one column at a time.

Today, It's also possible to get the history of all items in a list using OWSVR.DLL:
http://hostname/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={GUID}&IncludeVersions=TRUE&XMLDATA=TRUE
The downside here is that it works on the list level and returns all items. You cannot specify a single item.